# three20 with iphone device 2.2.1

Tags: iphone, three20

i use in my iphone application "three20" library but it's not work in iphone device 2.2.1.
anybody now if this project can run in this device and how can i solve it ?
thanks Alex

Comment: We can't help you unless you tell us why it isn't working. What errors are you seeing? Did you follow the instructions to set it up correctly? Are you sure you have the latest version? Are you sure the latest version is in a compileable state?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you received your answer by [asking on the Three20 Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/5a5da72041821f61).